# Qt versions for 6 architectures are missing

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk, qt5.9

I have just installed Qt 5.9.1 and want to make an app for Android (I'm using Windows 10).

I have installed the SDK, NDK and ant and specified the paths in the configuration. But Qt gives the following warning:

> Qt versions for 6 architectures are missing. To add the Qt versions,
>   select Options > Build & Run > Qt Versions

When I go to *Qt Versions* I can only see **Qt 5.9.1 MinGW 32bit**.

I've googled this and a solution to a similar issue was to download the Android version of Qt from the [Qt download page](https://www1.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2):

But that Android version is only 5.6. I'm gonna use Qt Quick Controls 2, which is not available until version 5.7, according to [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-index.html):

> Qt Quick Controls 2 provides a set of controls that can be used to
>   build complete interfaces in Qt Quick. The module was introduced in Qt
>   5.7.

Does anyone know what is causing this? Is there some other way I can get the files needed to build for Android and keep Qt version 5.9?